# Is distance irrelevant to time if two events are in the same inertial reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Assuming that there is some observer "O" at location 0, and there are two events A and B, with B occurring 1m farther from A. Both A and B are equipped with two synchronized clocks reading exactly the same time.

1 Would the two events be simultaneous from observer O's reference frame?

2 Are events simultaneous being in the same inertial reference frame regardless of their distance from the observer?

Comment: An event is a point in spacetime, so both A and B will have a time coordinate, and one or more spatial coordinates. They are simultaneos in O's frame if they have the same time coordinates...

Comment: How fast is O moving relative to A and B? See the Andromeda Paradox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer $O$ sets up some coordinates $t, x, y, z$ using their clock to measure times and their ruler to measure distances, and then using these coordinates they can measure the positions of $A$ and $B$ as $(t_a, x_a, y_a, z_a)$ and $(t_b, x_b, y_b, z_b)$. Then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous in $O$'s coordinates if $t_a = t_b$. This how we define the term *simultaneous*.

I would guess you are interested in whether clocks placed at different positions in $O$'s inertial frame can be synchronised and if so whether they will remain synchronised, and the answer to both questions is *yes*. We can place clocks at $O$'s position and at $A$ and $B$'s positions then synchronise them using [Einstein synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation). Then as long as all three observers stay in the same inertial frame all three clocks will remain synchronised and all three observers will agree on the times of events i.e. they will all agree on whether events are simultaneous or not.

In principle we can place a clock at every point in a coordinate system and then synchronise all the clocks using Einstein synchronisation. Then we can get the time of an event from the clock placed at the same point in space as the event. Since all the clocks are synchronised they will all agree about the time of the event.